# How to create dictionary<int, string> from IEnumearble<IEnumerable<int, string>>

Tags: c#, linq

have a complex Linq expression right here. At the moment I'm only able to create IEnumearble, but I need to parse to IEnumerable<int, string>. I have no clue how to take that 'string'.

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> uniqueColumns = test
     .Where(e => e.ToolParameters != null)
     .Select(x => x.ToolParameters.Select(u => u.ToolParameterTypeId))
     .Distinct();
uniqueColumnIds = uniqueColumns
     .SelectMany(a => a)
     .Distinct();
```

As you can see, I check if 'ToolParameters' is null. If it is not, then I select ' ToolParametersTypeId', but I also need to select 'ToolParameteresTypeName', but have no idea how...

After that, I need to parse that Ienumearble<Ienumearble<>> to only one Ienumerable because my goals is to have unique values from a bunch of lists. But I need to make a dictionary which consists of unique key,string values from a bunch of lists...

I have uniqueColumnIds, but I also need to get uniqueColumnNames and put them together to get a dictionary of key,value pairs. Maybe someone has any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Everything is confusing. Your title doesn't match your code which does not match your requirements. can you edit your post title and content so it match each other.

Comment: Do you not mean `Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<string>>`? Where the key is `ToolParametersTypeId` and the value is the corresponding `ToolParameteresTypeName`s?

Comment: Yes, but I need to get Dictionary<int, string>. String can't be enumerable.

Comment: Ok I think I understand; so is `ToolParametersTypeId` unique across all `ToolParameters`? If not, then you may have duplicate values and need `IEnumerable`.

Comment: It is unique. Both Id and Name is unique, but the way to get to them is very complex as you can see    EDIT. They can duplicate, but my task is to get only the unique ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary is not the correct structure, as each key can only appear once. If a `ToolParametersTypeId` has more than one corresponding `ToolParameteresTypeName` then you will need to discard all but one `ToolParameteresTypeName`. A more appropriate structure may be `IEnumerable<(int, string)>`:

```
IEnumerable<(int ToolParameterTypeId, string ToolParameteresTypeName)> uniqueColumns =
    test
    .Where(e => e.ToolParameters != null)
    .SelectMany(e => e.ToolParameters.Select(tp =>
        (tp.ToolParameterTypeId, tp.ToolParameteresTypeName)))
    .Distinct();
```

`SelectMany` flattens the nested `IEnumerable`s, and the nested `Select` projects each item into a `ValueTuple`.

Using `Distinct` on an `IEnumerable<ValueTuple>` then checks for equality based on the value of each tuple component, not by reference, so you will end with distinct pairs of `ToolParameterTypeId`, and `ToolParameteresTypeName`.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy.

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<(int key, string value)>> target = default; // replace default.
var dict = target.SelectMany(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.key, x => x.value);
```